# Android Facebook ShareLinkContent to be visible only in mobile Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

We have an Android app (also an iOS app in the future). We would like users to share particular contents from the app to their Facebook timeline.

It works quite well but the problem is that we do not have a web site for our product. Therefore we want the Facebook post to appear only in the Facebook app, but not in web. When clicked from (Facebook) web site, the link goes to Google Store. It is pointless in our case. Is there a way to achieve this?

Our code block looks like this:

```
String id = {generated by a post to https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts}
String url = "https://fb.me/" + id;

ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentDescription("Description")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url))
                    .setImageUrl("Image URL")
                    .build();

shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Om Facebook, there is no way to limit the audience of user generated content to a specific platform.